# Single Check Box Value Insert

Tags: php, html

How can i insert single checkbox value in mysql database in php.

```
Male <input type="checkbox" value="male" name="gender[]" >
Female <input type="checkbox" value="Female" name="gender[]">
```

Comment: your question is not clear . make it clear. you said insert into sql but you have only html tag here?

Answer (score 1):

**Male, Female kind of selection are always radio, not checkbox**. And do not give their name as array, as only one of them is selected at a time, so make following changes:

```
Male <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" >
Female <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender">
```

and get its value like:

```
$gender = $_REQUEST['gender'];
```

and insert it into database using `$gender`

Comment: ok but if i inserted gender through checkbox , how can i inserted?

Comment: But why? **can a person be male and female at the same time?**

Comment: @Doni Why you want to use checkbox? As you know it can't be multiple choice. For single choice there is radio

Answer (score 0):

You can check its state and insert according to it

```
Male <input type="radio" value="male" name="male" >
Female <input type="radio" value="Female" name="female">
```

In php code use validations like:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['gender'])) {
    $gender = $_REQUEST['gender'];
    //Code to insert this $gender in database
}
```